# How to update view behind the popover view on dismissal of the popover?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a View and a popover that appears on top of it, which alters data. I am trying to update the view/run a function on the main view (that is under the popover) once the popover is dismissed. I have tried numerous things including viewwillappear, but it isn't being registered as technically the view doesn't disappear since the popover is just above (And you can see part of the view from behind). If anyone can suggest how to call a function on the parent view when dismissing the popover (without crashing the app, as most of my attempts have), I would be very grateful! Thanks.

Update: I am attempting to do this with a modally presented vc now, and have attempted to use protocol callbacks but to no avail. Below is the code.

```
protocol MainVCDelegate: class {
func pushIt()
```

}

in the modally pushed view:

```
    weak var delegate: MainVCDelegate?


   @IBAction func changePartnerButton(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.pushIt()
    dismiss(animated: false)
 
}
```

in the main VC I implement the protocol and create the function to be run, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS 13 and iOS 14, you set yourself as the popover's presentation controller's delegate and implement `presentationControllerDidDismiss`. In iOS 12 and before, you set yourself as the popover's popover presentation controller's delegate and implement `popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover`.

Comment: I attempt to do this but when calling the delegate function in my popover function it asks me to give an argument of type UIPresentationController, which I do not have (using the regular one prompts me with a .type error)

Comment: I assure you that what I said to do is what you do. I can't see your code. You can see mine, however: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/4f916d628ea85407b28786707313bf2a99835e61/bk2ch09p481popoverInStoryboard/ch22p751popovers/ViewController.swift

Comment: I'm actually looking through that book right now! However, I am trying to dismiss the popover in code and cannot find the proper function to call since they all seem to be called too early or not called when dismissing the popover in code.

Comment: No methods are called when you dismiss the popover in code. You don't need a callback when you dismiss the popover in code, because it is your code that dismissed it. You get notified when the _user_ does something, not when _you_ do something.